# OEIS A227133 (square-free grid colourings)

Tags: coloring, oeis

This is a nice one: http://oeis.org/A227133  (see also http://oeisf.org/Poster15a.pdf)

I built a straightforward SAT encoding and found a(11) >= 72 because of

```
. . X X X X X X X . X 
X X X . X . X . . X X 
X . X X . . . X X X . 
X X . . X . . . X . X 
. X X X . X . . . X X 
. X . . X X X X X X . 
X X X . . X . X . X X 
. X . X X X . . . X . 
X X . X . . X X X . X 
X . . X . . X . X X X 
X . X X X X X X . . X
```

and a(12) >= 84 by

```
. X X X X . X . X . X X 
X X . X . . X X X X . . 
X . . X . X X . . . X . 
X X . . . . X . . X X X 
. X X X X . . X . X . X 
X . X . X X X X X X X . 
X . X X . X . X . . X X 
. X X . . X X . . X . X 
X X . . X X . . . X X X 
. X . X . X X X X . . X 
X X X X X . X . X . X . 
X . . X . . . X X X X X
```

but I have no idea whether these configurations are maximal.

What is the asymptotic growth?

Comment: Sorry about the first comment, I had first misunderstood the condition.